# How to send data collected by javascript via form

Tags: php, yii

At now in view I have a ajax button and pass data like this

```
echo CHtml::ajaxButton(...,'js:$("#a").sortable("serialize")',..)
```

but how to pass this data with a form if i want to use form model?

Comment: Add the javascript code for that to the js parameter as well. What stops you from doing so?

Comment: [See this if it can help you out][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit

it will give some idea atleast

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is native to Yii, so for a start, use that.

Then just do something like (untested):

```
$('form').submit( function() {
  $.post('/url/', $(this).serialize()); 
});
```